# Errror after migrating from Vaadin23 to Vaadin24: Invalid option in transform() call: "jsxDev"

Tags: vaadin, vaadin24

I migrate my Java SpringBoot Application from Vaadin23 to Vaadin 24.3.7 (and also SpringBoot from 2.75 to 3.2.3).

After starting the Application I got the following error:

```
...
2024-03-26T13:48:48.980+01:00  INFO 17112 --- [  restartedMain] c.d.VaadinApplication   : Started VaadinApplication in 14.479 seconds (process running for 15.9)
2024-03-26T13:49:13.716+01:00 ERROR 17112 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.f.s.frontend.TaskRunDevBundleBuild   : Command `C:\Program Files\dev\node_js20\node.exe C:\Prog\dev\git\vaadin-app\node_modules\vite\bin\vite.js build` failed:
vite v5.1.1 building for production...
transforming...
3 modules transformed.
error during build:
Error: [vaadin:build-sw] Transform failed with 1 error:
C:\Prog\dev\git\vaadin-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:241:12: error: Invalid option in transform() call: "jsxDev"
file: C:/Prog/dev/git/vaadin-app/target/sw.ts:241:12

Invalid option in transform() call: "jsxDev"

    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Prog\dev\git\vaadin-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1475:15)
    at C:\Prog\dev\git\vaadin-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1298:20
    at C:\Prog\dev\git\vaadin-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:611:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Prog\dev\git\vaadin-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:708:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Prog\dev\git\vaadin-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:578:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

Comment: Have you properly cleaned your project, including removing generated files, locks, ...?

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I didn´t delete everything. Now the Login-View appears.